# AtomicInteger : Thread safe unconditional increment/decrement counter (atomically incremented/decremented from multiple threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic

Looking at the Java 11 source code for [AtomicInteger](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#L215) & [Unsafe](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java#L2334), I concluded that if one only wants a thread safe *unconditional* increment/decrement counter (just atomically incremented/decremented unconditionally from multiple threads) one can just use the [AtomicInteger's](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#L215) unconditional increment/decrement methods (like `AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet()` or `AtomicInteger#decrementAndGet()` or the related variants) out of the box to achieve that.

This since they already ensure that the call to the increment/decrement methods always increases/decreases the value by 1 atomically even when invoked from multiple threads without any race condition issues (`getAndAddInt` code in [Unsafe](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe.java#L2334) clearly retries `weakCompareAndSetInt()` until it succeeds for an increment by 1).

If this is the case, isn't the below statement incorrect/needless in [this Baeldung post on atomic variables](https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables)? Why does one need to code this `increment()` method for it to be a thread safe counter, why can't one just use the methods I noted above?

Or am I missing or misunderstanding something?

```
A thread-safe counter implemented with AtomicInteger is shown in the example below:

public class SafeCounterWithoutLock {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public int getValue() {
        return counter.get();
    }
    public void increment() {
        while(true) {
            int existingValue = getValue();
            int newValue = existingValue + 1;
            if(counter.compareAndSet(existingValue, newValue)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's nonsense.  It's a nonsensical way to use AtomicInteger, and it's a nonsensical way to use compareAndSet.

Comment: OK thanks, I had submitted an [issue](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/issues/13281) earlier on GIT

Comment: The interesting thing about a CAS retry loop like that is that you can synthesize any atomic RMW you want (on a single variable), including multiply, clear lowest set bit, or whatever.  For cases like increment or add, yes, you should *definitely* use the standard functions instead of rolling your own; some ISAs (notably x86-64 and ARMv8.1) can do atomic increment or add in a single instruction, with hardware arbitration for access to the cache line so they never fail to get any work done after getting ownership of a cache line.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you. Yes, I see the value in doing this CAS externally for other things like the multiply, etc. that you note, but not for counter, its misleading for a viewer of that tutorial who doesn't look at the source code of AtomicInteger to think an external CAS is needed.

Comment: Yeah, that tutorial is pretty bad; it implies the only RMW operation available is CAS.  It vaguely hints at one point that there are operations other than CAS, and it links the class, but that's its only example of an atomic RMW.

Comment: PS: the code of many of the methods in the Atomic classes isn't the same as what is being executed. Many of these methods are intrensified. The CAS loop for e.g. an increment is replaced by the appropriate atomic instruction like 'lock add' on the X86.

Comment: @pveentjer I can't figure out what you mean by 'intrensified' - something lost in translation?  (No criticism intended).  Inlined?  Some verb formation meaning 'replaced by  intrinsic operations'?

Comment: Intrensified means that a piece of code is being replaced by a different piece of code (often a lot faster). If you look at the AtomicInteger.getAndAddInt you can see a cas-loop. But you can also see the @IntrensicCandidate annotation above which indicates that this code is intrensified and in this case it could be intrensified on the X86 to a 'lock add' that doesn't need a loop. For more info see https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-intrinsics